# Applescript to Get Mail Information

Tags: macos, email, applescript

This is my script:

```
tell application "Mail"
    set theMessage to selection
    set theSubject to subject of theMessage
    set theBody to content of theMessage
end tell
```

I don't even have it doing anything yet. Still I get this error on any selected message:

```
tell application "Mail"
    get selection
        --> {message id 73707 of mailbox "INBOX" of account id "6E0B3832-1B5E-4689-9C8A-8D6294A0C4A4"}
Result:
error "Can’t get subject of {message id 73707 of mailbox \"INBOX\" of account id \"6E0B3832-1B5E-4689-9C8A-8D6294A0C4A4\" of application \"Mail\"}." number -1728 from «class subj» of {«class mssg» id 73707 of «class mbxp» "INBOX" of «class mact» id "6E0B3832-1B5E-4689-9C8A-8D6294A0C4A4"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried many variations including entering delay commands.

Answer (score 0):

The selection is not a message but a list of one or more messages. Try this :

```
tell application "Mail"
    set theSelection to the selection
    repeat with theMessage in theSelection
        set theSubject to subject of theMessage
        set theBody to content of theMessage
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Thanx... Guess I didn't realize that Applescript treats the selection as a list even if the list is just one item long.